# Two clusters on EKS, how to switch between them

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I am not exactly sure what's going on which is why I am asking this question. When I run this command:

```
kubectl config get-clusters
```

I get:

```
arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:91xxxxx371:cluster/eks-cluster-1
arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:91xxxxx371:cluster/eks1
```

then I run:

```
kubectl config current-context
```

and I get:

```
arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:91xxxxx371:cluster/eks-cluster-1
```

and if I run `kubectl get pods`, I get the expected output.
But how do I switch to the other cluster/context? what's the difference between the cluster and context? I can't figure out how these commands differ:

When I run them, I still get the pods from the wrong cluster:

```
root@4c2ab870baaf:/# kubectl config set-context arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:913617820371:cluster/eks1

Context "arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:913617820371:cluster/eks1" modified.

root@4c2ab870baaf:/#
root@4c2ab870baaf:/# kubectl get pods
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
apache-spike-579598949b-5bjjs   1/1     Running   0          14d
apache-spike-579598949b-957gv   1/1     Running   0          14d
apache-spike-579598949b-k49hf   1/1     Running   0          14d

root@4c2ab870baaf:/# kubectl config set-cluster arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:91xxxxxx371:cluster/eks1

Cluster "arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:91xxxxx371:cluster/eks1" set.

root@4c2ab870baaf:/# kubectl get pods
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
apache-spike-579598949b-5bjjs   1/1     Running   0          14d
apache-spike-579598949b-957gv   1/1     Running   0          14d
apache-spike-579598949b-k49hf   1/1     Running   0          14d
```

so I really don't know how to properly switch between clusters or contexts and also switch the auth routine when doing so.

For example:

```
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:91xxxxx371:cluster/ignitecluster
    user: arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:91xxxx371:cluster/ignitecluster
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:91xxxxx371:cluster/ignitecluster
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:91xxxx371:cluster/teros-eks-cluster
    user: arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:91xxxxx371:cluster/teros-eks-cluster
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:91xxxxx371:cluster/teros-eks-cluster
```

Answer (score 17):

To clarify on the difference between `set-context` and `use-context`

A context is a group of access parameters. Each context contains a Kubernetes cluster, a user, and a namespace. So when you do **set-context**, you just adding context details to your configuration file `~/.kube/config`, but it doesn't switch you to that context, while **use-context** actually does.

Thus, as Vasily mentioned, in order to switch between clusters run

```
kubectl config use-context <CONTEXT-NAME>
```

Also, if you run `kubectl config get-contexts` you will see list of contexts with indication of the current one.

Comment: in addition, it is possible to rename context: kubectl config rename-context <a big old name from get-contexts> <a new short name that makes sense>

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
kubectl config use-context arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:91xxxxx371:cluster/eks-cluster-1
```

and

```
kubectl config use-context arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:91xxxxx371:cluster/eks
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [kubectx](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx) for managing your contexts.

---

**Usage**

View all contexts (the current context is bolded):

```
$kubectx
    arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:12234567:cluster/eks_app
  ->gke_my_second_cluster
    my-rnd
    my-prod
```

Switch to other context:

```
$ kubectx my-rnd
Switched to context "my-rnd".
```

---

Bonus:
In the same link - check also the *kubens* tool.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best command to switch between different EKS clusters.

I use it every day.

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --name example
```

Documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/eks/update-kubeconfig.html

Answer (score 0):

You may try Lens - https://k8slens.dev/ which would help managing multiple EKS clusters easier through its GUI